# Argument label (Contents Of File :, options:, error:, ) do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am following this tutorial MapKit Tutorial: Getting Started -RAY WENDERLICH. Here i am trying to parse JSON data. 
the following is the helper method to the class:

```
func loadInitialData() {
   // 1
   let fileName = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PublicArt", ofType: "json");
   var readError : NSError?
   var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileName!, options: NSDataReadingOptions(0),
error: &readError)!

   // 2
   var error: NSError?
   let jsonObject: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, 
   options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &error)

   // 3
   if let jsonObject = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject] where error == nil,
      // 4
      let jsonData = JSONValue.fromObject(jsonObject)?["data"]?.array {
      for artworkJSON in jsonData {
          if let artworkJSON = artworkJSON.array,
              // 5
              artwork = Artwork.fromJSON(artworkJSON) {
              artworks.append(artwork)
          }
      }
   }
}
```

But i am getting two errors:

1)  **Error : argument label (Contents Of File :, options:, error:, ) do not match any available overloads** at line

```
 var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileName!, options:     NSDataReadingOptions(rawValue: 0),
                              error: &readError)!
```

2) **Extra arguement 'error' in call** at line

```
let jsonObject: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                                                                        options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &error)
```

Please can someone help me.

Comment: This is the old syntax. Don't follow outdated tutorials.

Comment: @Code could you please help me with the new one?

Comment: Use the migrator / converter (Menu Edit > Convert)

Comment: The "error" management has changed in Swift2.2: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10