# Web Service Apps in JSON with UITableView using Swift Language

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS and was learning about web services. I came across this tutorial http://www.thedarkdev.com/webservice-swift-ios8-json-uitableview.html. I tried the program given but i am getting these errors:

1.**'objectForKeyedSubscript' is unavailable: use subscripting** at line

```
let text: NSMutableString = tmpDict.objectForKeyedSubscript(thetitle) as! NSMutableString
let detail: NSMutableString = tmpDict.objectForKeyedSubscript(thedate) as! NSMutableString
```

2. **Extra argument 'error' in call** at line

```
var jsonSource: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(URLrequest, returningResponse: response , error: err)
```

3. **Use of unresolved identifier 'jsonObjects'** at line

```
for dataDict : AnyObject in jsonObjects
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,NSURLConnectionDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {



@IBOutlet var tableData: UITableView!

let thetitle: NSString = "title"
let thedate: NSString = "date"
let day_thai: NSString = "day_thai"
let err: NSError? = nil
let dictionary:NSDictionary? = nil
let myObject: NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var urlPath = "http://www.linezeed.com/calendar.php?api_key=p24567739e33xcbnfg0"
    var jsonURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var URLrequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: jsonURL)
    var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil

   var jsonSource: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(URLrequest, returningResponse: response , error: err)

  //let jsonObjects = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonSource, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSMutableArray

    do {
        if let jsonObjects = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonSource, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSMutableArray {
            print(jsonObjects)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    var dataDict: NSDictionary
    for dataDict : AnyObject in jsonObjects {
        var title_data: NSString = dataDict.objectForKey("title") as NSString
        var date_data: NSString = dataDict.objectForKey("date") as NSString
        println("วันหยุดคือ:"+title_data+" ตรงกับวันที่:"+date_data+"")

        let dictionary = [thetitle: title_data, thedate: date_data]
        myObject.addObject(dictionary)


    }
    print(myObject.count)
    self.tableData.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

//Table
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return myObject.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell{

    let tableCell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    var tmpDict: NSDictionary = myObject[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let text: NSMutableString = tmpDict.objectForKeyedSubscript(thetitle) as! NSMutableString
    let detail: NSMutableString = tmpDict.objectForKeyedSubscript(thedate) as! NSMutableString
    tableCell.textLabel?.text=text as String
    tableCell.detailTextLabel?.text = detail as String

    return tableCell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: 2.: Error Management has changed in Swift (since 2.0 I think). 3.: `jsonObject` is not defined in the scope that is throwing the error. It's defined in the "do/catch", but not outside.

Comment: @Larme Can u please elaborate? I did not understand.

Comment: You are using an old tutorial. Swift has changed since. It's the same issue of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982942/argument-label-contents-of-file-options-error-do-not-match-any-availab